# scopes can't find files in other folders

Tags: unity, unity-dash, dropbox, owncloud-client

I've just made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04. I don't use the default folders of Documents and so, because I used some online accounts (Owncloud and Dropbox). The problem is that I can't find any results in those folders when searching from the dash. Do I need an extra complement different than the default ones? I don't find options of adding extra folders to the search; and I thought that default search includes the whole system. Is it true? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The default search via the files scope doesn't search all files on the system. It only searches the zeitgeist history (activity log). You'd need to open those files from the file manager to get them to show up in the history, for example. There doesn't seem to be any scopes for searching the remote owncloud or dropbox hosts for data.